# Is the alternative operator in ABNF commutative?

Tags: parsing, abnf

Is the alternative operator (`/`) in [Augmented Backus-Naur Form](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234) commutative?

For example, is `s = a / b` the same as `s = b / a`?

Comment: If not, I would be interested to know if it is left-associative or right-associative.

Comment: @GeoffCox, the `alternation` rule defined in ABNF's self-describing grammar (see [RFC 5234, Section 4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5234#section-4)) is right-recursive, therefore `/` is right-associative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found any primary sources on BNF or ABNF which explicitly specify `/` semantics when both sides would yield valid matches. They don't allude to context-free grammars and their allowance for non-determinism either. If anyone knows of clarifying references please share.

**EDIT**: Tony's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54951921/204305) points out [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) from 2003 specifies the semantics of ABNF alternation, at least as it's used in that document.

#### [RFC 5234: Augmented BNF for Syntax Specifications: ABNF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234) (2008)

The introduction contrasts BNF and ABNF (with emphasis added here):

> Over the years, a modified version of Backus-Naur Form (BNF), called Augmented BNF (ABNF), has been popular among many Internet specifications.  It balances compactness and simplicity with reasonable representational power.  In the early days of the Arpanet, each specification contained its own definition of ABNF.  This included the email specifications, [RFC733](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc733) and then [RFC822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) , which came to be the common citations for defining ABNF.  The current document separates those definitions to permit **selective reference**.
>
> The differences between standard BNF and ABNF involve naming rules, repetition, alternatives, **order-independence**, and value ranges.

"Selective reference" and "order-independence" may relate to alternation ordering semantics, but it's unclear.

#### [RFC 822: Standard for the Format of ARPA Internet Text Messages](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) (1982)

Unless I'm missing something, the cited RFCs don't specify `/` semantics either. Section 2.2 evades the problem.

> **2.2.  RULE1 / RULE2:  ALTERNATIVES**

> Elements separated by slash ("/") are alternatives.   There-
> fore "foo / bar" will accept foo or bar.

Various rule definitions show they recognize the practical importance of avoiding ambiguity. For example, here's how RFC 822 defines `optional-field` and its dependencies:

```
 optional-field =
             /  "Message-ID"        ":"   msg-id
             /  "Resent-Message-ID" ":"   msg-id
             /  "In-Reply-To"       ":"  *(phrase / msg-id)
             /  "References"        ":"  *(phrase / msg-id)
             /  "Keywords"          ":"  #phrase
             /  "Subject"           ":"  *text
             /  "Comments"          ":"  *text
             /  "Encrypted"         ":" 1#2word
             /  extension-field              ; To be defined
             /  user-defined-field           ; May be pre-empted

 extension-field =
               <Any field which is defined in a document
                published as a formal extension to this
                specification; none will have names beginning
                with the string "X-">
 
 user-defined-field =
               <Any field which has not been defined
                in this specification or published as an
                extension to this specification; names for
                such fields must be unique and may be
                pre-empted by published extensions>
```

#### [The Syntax and Semantics of the Proposed International Algebraic Language of the Zurich ACM-GAMM Conference](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/ALGOL/paper/Backus-Syntax_and_Semantics_of_Proposed_IAL.pdf) (Backus 1958)

BNF comes from IAL notation. The paper introduces ̅o̅r "metalinguistic connective", which is intuitively related to `/`. However, it also dodges the ambiguous choice problem and presumably just uses it carefully.

### Recommendation

Due to unspecified semantics my suggestion is to *treat every possible match in an `alternation` rule as valid*. When the grammar isn't carefully designed to avoid ambiguity this interpretation can result in multiple valid parse trees for the same input. Addressing ambiguous parses as they occur is safer than forging ahead with an unintentionally valid parse tree.

Alternatively, if you have influence over how the grammar is specified you could consider a notation with clearer semantics. For example, [Parsing Expression Grammar: A Recognition-Based Syntactic Foundation](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/parsing:popl04.pdf) (Ford 2004) gives alternatives deterministic *prioritized choice* semantics (left-most match wins).

Answer (score 3):

Some RFCs clarify this explicitly, with for example IMAPv4's RFC3501 including specification of PEG-like behaviour in [RFC 3501 section 9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-9):

> In the case of alternative or optional rules in which a later rule
> overlaps an earlier rule, the rule which is listed earlier MUST take
> priority.  For example, "\Seen" when parsed as a flag is the \Seen
> flag name and not a flag-extension, even though "\Seen" can be parsed
> as a flag-extension.  Some, but not all, instances of this rule are
> noted below.

I don't know how common such disambiguation (hah) is, though. Many other RFCs I've looked at (I've been implementing an ABNF parser library in recent days) just leave it unspecified. Many RFC ABNF grammars are unambiguous (e.g. RFC8259 (JSON)); however, many are ambiguous (e.g. RFC5322 (Internet Messages)) and require fixups to work with an ambiguity-preserving parser :-(